# ionic framework FCM plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

By now I could send notification too all the apps successfully via firebase console ([firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/)).
The problem is that I cannot send notification to specific device.
This is my code in run function :

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      FCMPlugin.getToken(
      function(token){
          alert("fire base token :)    :"+token);
      },
      function(err){
          console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
      }
  )
```

});

I get the token and when I use firebase to send it to specific device it says that the "token is invalid/" 
What part is wrong? 
Am I misunderstanding something? 
My project is ionic framework tabs sample code.

Comment: Are you sending the message from the Firebase Console?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes I am trying to send to specific device via Firebase Console

Comment: It's hard to tell with the given details. Can you try and validate the token?

Comment: How can I validate the token? It seems that the token is right in terms of the format. (I am really new to this notification process)

Comment: See the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#auth). Specifically, *If you want to confirm the validity of a registration token, you can do so by replacing "ABC" with the registration token*. (No worries. I'll try to help you out as much as I can).

Answer (score 0):

Use blow code

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova) {
        FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function(data){

                if(data.wasTapped){
                   // $state.go('message', {id:data.pageId});
                  // $location.path('app/userList');
                    console.log('onNotification tapped true');
                } else {
                    console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxx"+data.message);
                }
            },
            function(msg){
             // alert("asdf"+msg)
                console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
                FCMPlugin.getToken(
                 function(token){
                   //alert(token);
                   window.localStorage.setItem("deviceId",token)
                 },
                 function(err){
                   console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
                 }
               )
            },
            function(err){
             // alert("fjkjg"+err)
                console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

})